# Referential integrity based on data more than a table away

Tags: database-design, constraint, referential-integrity

Notes on tables A, B, C, D, E

- `B.aid` and `C.aid` reference `A.aid`.
- `D.cid` references `C.cid` and `D.did` is the primary key.  `D` is a `C`.
- `cid` and `did` are pre-assigned and I cannot change them (they need to remain separate despite the is-a).
- `E` has information that depends on its primary key (`bid`, `did`) with `bid` referencing `B.bid` and `did` referencing `D.did`.

Is there a way to make sure that the `bid` and `did` of a given row in `E` reference rows in `B` and `D` that reference the same row in `A` (through `C` in the case of `D`)?

So far I've come up with

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    aid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE b (
    bid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    aid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES a ( aid ),
    UNIQUE ( bid, aid )
);

CREATE TABLE c (
    cid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    aid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES a ( aid ),
    UNIQUE ( cid, aid )
);

CREATE TABLE d (
    did INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    cid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES c ( cid ),
    UNIQUE ( did, cid )
);

CREATE TABLE e (
    bid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES b ( bid ),
    cid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES c ( cid ),
    did INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES d ( did ),
    dcid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    baid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    caid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( bid, did ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( bid, baid ) REFERENCES b ( bid, aid ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( cid, caid ) REFERENCES c ( cid, aid ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( did, dcid ) REFERENCES d ( did, cid ),
    CHECK ( baid = caid AND cid = dcid )
);
```

Is there a better way to create `E` that doesn't seem so complicated and redundant?

Comment: Yes, there is. Add `aid` to all tables and modify FK and UNIQUE constraints accordingly

Comment: Oh, I see you came up with something like that. It needs correction though in some points.